# How to prevent the initial pytorch variable from changing using a function?

Tags: function, pytorch, tensor

I want to apply a function to the variable `x` and saved as `y`. But why the `x` is also changed? How to prevent it?

```
import torch
def minus_min(raw):
  for col_i in range(len(raw[0])):
    new=raw
    new[:,col_i] = (raw[:,col_i] - raw[:,col_i].min())
  return new

x=torch.tensor([[0,1,2,3,4],
                [2,3,4,0,8],
                [0,1,2,3,4]])
y=minus_min(x)
print(y)
print(x)
```

output:

```
tensor([[0, 0, 0, 3, 0],
        [2, 2, 2, 0, 4],
        [0, 0, 0, 3, 0]])
tensor([[0, 0, 0, 3, 0],
        [2, 2, 2, 0, 4],
        [0, 0, 0, 3, 0]])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because this assignment:

```py
new[:,col_i] = (raw[:,col_i] - raw[:,col_i].min())
```

is an in-place operation. Therefore, `x` and `y` will share the underlying `.data`.

The smallest change that would solve this issue would be to make a copy of `x` inside the function:

```py
def minus_min(raw):
  new = raw.clone()  # <--- here
  for col_i in range(len(raw[0])):
    new[:,col_i] = raw[:,col_i] - raw[:,col_i].min()
  return new
```

If you want, you can simplify your function (and remove the `for` loop):

```py
y = x - x.min(dim=0).values
```